# Constraint layout misbehaves after updates

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

When I use `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2` I got following output.

[image]

But when I update constraint layout to `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0` I am getting following strange output.

[image]

All my fields are gone. Don't know why. Anyway right now I am revert back to old version. But I want to know whether I have to change anything in xml or it is a bug?

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta6'`

Comment: Recheck your constraints to make them work with the new version. You are probably doing something wrong. Feel free to post your xml